# I have to write a c++ code that inputs a name in string and outputs it in a different order

Tags: c++

//This program inputs a student's name in the following form: lastName, firstName middleName.
//The program will convert the name to the following form : firstName middleName lastName.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name, str, substr;
    int pos;
    cout << "Enter a name in the following format: last name, first name middle name" << endl;
    cin >> str.length (name);
    pos = str.find(", ");
    cout << "The students name is " << str.substr(pos + 1, str.length() - pos - 1) << str.substr(0, pos - 1) << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

//This is what I have so far. I think that am stuck on the cin statement and I don't know what it should be. When I run the code, it doe not output a name.

Comment: if this is a homework for school, sharing the teacher's requirements would make more sense

Answer (score 1):

Well ... even I think you don't have any clue what you're doing there, let's see where your mistakes are.

Let's take the first wrong part of your initial code.

```
    cin >> str.length(name);
```

`name` has no value so far, so `str.length()` will return `0` but ... you want to get the name here. But what you're trying here is like 'Please get a input by user and write that user input to the method `str.length()`. Do you think that this sounds right?

So what you have to do is

```
    cin >> str;
```

But now, let's help yourself and simply print, what the user has entered:

```
    cin >> str;
    cout << str;
```

When the user enters `Doe, John Max` the output will be `Doe,`. This is because the input stream just handles a whitespace like a symbol to stop reading. To get this working, search for `std::getline` and afterwards think about your usage of `substr`.